# Updating Visual Studio Projects and Solutions Locations through batch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to update the Visual Studio 2012 Projects and Solutions Locations through command line and/or registry edits post install? We're looking to update the top 3 locations through a script in this screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is loaded from the VS .settings file, which is typically in %userprofile%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\ folder. The entries are under

```
<ToolsOptionsSubCategory 
    name="ProjectsAndSolution"
    RegisteredName="ProjectsAndSolution"    
    PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">    
       <PropertyValue name="ProjectsLocation">c:\projects</PropertyValue>
        ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, my company must have customized the install slightly. When I go to "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\" a "Settings" directory doesn't exist there. My settings is actually stored in the same location as my documents (H:\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings), on a share drive denoted by h: drive. Any idea how we can determine the location of the current VS settings file location programatically?

Comment: Take a look and see if you have the following registry entries - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Profile - AutoSaveFile, DefaultSettingsDirectory

Comment: I see defaults there for locations, I assume the values are only taken from here though upon resetting the settings? Any ideas of where we may find a pointer directly to the current vssettings file so that we can edit the settings directly? Or perhaps that's based off of the "VisualStudioLocation" registry key? And the Settings path is just appended to this and always named CurrentSettings.vssettings?

Comment: I * think * that the settings are always in CurrentSettings. Here is a thread on a somewhat similar subject, http://forums.asp.net/t/1369276.aspx mentioning how to reset settings from command line by using a specific settings file. So I * think * that if you create a settings file by setting up VS in the dialogue and exporting them to a file, it might give a way to automate what you need to do. ** I think ** :)